How to know the right SDK environment for every imported project
I'm downloading a lot of Java Spring and JavaFX files from Github to continue my learning trajectory. But only seldom can I create the right environment to view other people's work.
I've got about 7 SDK versions that I can substitute but not a lot of success here. I continue to get icons that look like this.
error icon
Right now I'm focused on Maven, not as much Gradle. I'm not afraid to ask newbie questions here because I know this is a major obstacle for everyone at the beginning of their Java journey.

Which version of JavaFX you need should be documented by the projects you clone. Then just make sure to have the JavaFX SDK for the target operating system and CPU architecture (which depends entirely on the computer you're running the project on, not the project's code). However, if the project is managed by Maven or Gradle and is designed to work with Java 11+, then the project likely declares dependencies on JavaFX in the POM file/build script. In that case, the build tool will handle downloading the correct JavaFX from Maven Central (you don't need a local JavaFX SDK).

As for your image, that looks more like the project is using a non-standard directory layout, and so the IDE needs to be configured to understand it (e.g., which directories are source roots, which are resource roots, etc.). Though again, if the project is managed by Maven or Gradle, you should be able to simply import the project as a "Maven project" or "Gradle project" and the IDE will autoconfigure itself.

One downloaded project I'm trying now says in its read me file that it requires SDK 11.0.10 and a JavaFX SDK of 11.0.2. Imported the Bellsoft Liberica version to make sure the the JavaFX was there. Still no compatibility. Maybe the fact that it was created with a different IDE is the problem. No gradle or POM file in sight. I just don't have the arcane knowledge to tweak IntelliJ out of this needless mire of perplexity. Your input has shined some light on all this though.

You should be more specific in your question (edit the question to improve it).  Provide a link to the project you are trying to use.  Write exact, complete instructions that somebody (e.g. a colleague) could follow to replicate your issue, without needing to ask any additional info.  Otherwise, you won't receive much assistance.  There is no "right" SDK environment for every project, what to use depends on the project and would be documented for the project or selected by the project build scripts.
